# Выбор нескольких уникальных максимальных значений из одной таблицы по id в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно выбрать комментарии с максимальным рейтингом для новостей из таблицы по id.
В первой таблице список новостей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во второй список комментариев:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно выбрать комментарии с максимальным рейтингом для каждой новости. Если рейтинг совпадает, показать первое выбранное значение.

Использую такой запрос.

```
SELECT n.id, n.title, t.comment, t.rating
FROM news n 
JOIN (
  SELECT a.rating rating, a.comment, a.news_id 
  FROM comments a
  RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT r.news_id, MAX(r.rating) rating
    FROM comments r
    GROUP BY r.news_id
  ) b ON b.news_id = a.news_id AND b.rating = a.rating
) t ON t.news_id = n.id
```

Если рейтинг комментариев совпадает, то выводятся сразу два, вместо одного. Группировать не получается, так как поле комментарий не совпадает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, каким образом можно отобразить только один комментарий к каждой новости с максимальным рейтингом?

Comment: какая версия mysql?

Comment: На OpenServer MySQL-5.7. На сервер пока не ставил.

Comment: ```Если рейтинг совпадает, показать первое выбранное значение.``` - нужно именно первое? или можно случайное?

Comment: Можно случайное, не так важно.

Comment: @DenVebber, Не могли бы вы использовать MySQL v.8.0? Было бы намного проще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться запросом ниже - он выведет случайный максимальный комментарий для записи:

```
select n.id, n.title, cc.comment, cc.rating from news n join (select c1.news_id, c1.rating, min(c1.comment) as comment
from comments c1
left join comments c2 on c1.news_id=c2.news_id and c2.rating>c1.rating
where c2.rating is null
group by c1.news_id, c1.rating) cc on n.id=cc.news_id
```

Если есть возможность перейти на MySQL 8 - более предпочтительно использовать `INNER JOIN LATERAl` - с ним запрос позволит брать именно самый первый комментарий:

```
select n.id, n.title, cc.comment, cc.rating
from news n INNER JOIN LATERAl (select c.news_id, c.comment, c.rating
from comments c
where n.id=c.news_id
order by c.rating desc, c.id
limit 1) cc on n.id=cc.news_id
```

Пример работы можно посмотреть [тут](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4618999fe925a08585da22ebc197a0c0)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Подошло. Полезный сервис https://dbfiddle.uk/. Не знал о нём раньше. Только не понял как работает min(c1.comment)

Comment: @DenVebber все просто - группируем записи по id новости и оценке, а затем находим минимальное значение комментария для этой группы. вы можете увидеть, что несмотря на то, что у комментария 'Comment 4' id больше - в этом варианте выбирается именно он, т.к. в случае сортировки он идет раньше

Comment: Понял. Спасибо)

Comment: А как быть, если нужно вытащить ещё одно поле из comments?
Например я добавляю в comments поле user_id (id пользователя, который добавил комментарий). При попытке добавить поле в join (select c1.user_id... ругается, что нет группировки по полю. А если группировать, то снова появляются лишние строки. Если в первый SELECT добавлять cc.user_id, то его не видит.

Comment: Перешёл на MySQL 8. Второй запрос помог.

Comment: Хороший ответ. +1 с моей стороны.